# Using touch command and wildcard how to solve?

Tags: shell, wildcards, brace-expansion

In order to demonstrate the use of 'wildcard' characters, issue a command to create the following empty files in your current directory:

```
a1  a11  a123  a1234  a23  a22  a3 1  11  123
```

someone told me to do this for him with the touch command. I tried 'touch a[*] [1-123] but did not work. please give me any solution

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a filename globbing pattern to generate filenames unless the pattern matches existing filenames.

Doing `touch a*[123]` (or whatever globbing pattern) in an *empty* directory would under normal circumstances just create the file `a*[123]`.

Brace expansions, on the other hand, generate strings on the command line without looking for existing names in the filesystem.

So, depending on what you mean by "wildcards", this may or may not be done at all.

---

You may tell your friend that if it takes longer time to figure out how to arrange the correct brace expansions to create the filenames than actually typing them out on the command line, then it's better just to type the filenames out literally. Brace expansions are supposed to be a *shortcut*.

However, if the filenames had been a bit more uniform, such as

```
1 12 123 a1 a12 a123 a11 a22 a33
```

then you could have used

```
$ touch {,a}1{,2{,3}} a{11,22,33}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use it as following.

```
touch a{1,3,11,22,23,123,1234} {1,11,123}
```

if you had a regular sequences like 0, 10, 20, 30 it could be done easily with the command as follows.

```
touch a{0..30..10}
```

Comment: if i want to do that in current directory then it is not working

Comment: there is nothing related to if you are in which path except if you have had those _names_ in current working directory